# Concatenate 2 Integers

Tags: java

I want to combine the values of 2 Integers into one. I tried this:

```
private String parseExpDate(Integer month, Integer year) {

    Integer last_digits = year % 100;

    StringBuilder concatenated = new StringBuilder();
    concatenated.append(month);
    concatenated.append(last_digits);
    return concatenated.toString();
}
```

But I have to convert it into String. For example, if I have `11` for month and `2019` for year I want to get `1119` at the end as Integer. Is this possible?

Comment: Did you try looking it up? Try reading about the `toString()` method

Comment: Just convert it to a string, combine them, then convert it back to an int and return that.

Comment: I'm not sure why this question gets so many downvotes? The OP posted their existing code , which works, but returns a String - and is asking for a way to get an Integer. Of course, they can call `Integer.parseInt` but there is a much easier way. I don't see much bad about this question; far better than the hundreds of people asking for The Codez the whole day.

Comment: As an aside, is their any point in your paramaters having type `Integer`? `int` would be the natural choice, and the recommended one unless you have a very specific reason for `Integer`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you are working with `Dates` I would like to use to use `LocalDate` with `DateTimeFormatter` like so :

```
private String parseExpDate(Integer year, Integer month) {
    LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of(year, month, 1);
    return ld.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMuu"));
}
```

---

```
System.out.println(parseExpDate(11, 2019));
=> 1119
```

---

#### Based on Ole V.V. comment

You can use `YearMonth` instead of `LocalDate` like so :

```
private String parseExpDate(Integer month, Integer year) {
    YearMonth ym = YearMonth.of(month, year);
    return ym.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMuu"));
}
```

> I want to get 1119 at the end as Integer

to get an int you can use `Integer.valueOf()` or `Integer.parseInt()` like this :

```
private int parseExpDate(Integer month, Integer year) {
    YearMonth ym = YearMonth.of(month, year);
    String dt = ym.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMuu"));
    return Integer.parseInt(dt);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What about multiplying the month by 100 so move it two digits to the left, and then adding the last two digits of the year to it? (You already have code to get the last two digits of the year in your question: `year % 100`)

```
int combined = 100 * month + year % 100;
```